# Enable https using Rewrite Rule for specific URLs

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, ssl

I am new to Apache and I am finding it extremely difficult to understand the rewrite rule syntax.

Here is my setup:
I have a Wordpress MU site at mydomain.com
I have parked domains site1, site2.com that point to mydomain.com

What I want:
I want this URL http://mydomain.com/wp-login.php to redirect to the same address but with https first. I have seen several tutorials on how to do this but there is a problem.

My problem:
If I use something like

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

this also redirects my other sites to https versions because they are parked domains and effectively loading the same htaccess code; since the certificate I have is only for mydomain.com I get certificate errors.

I need to only secure pages on the mydomain.com but only the wp-login.php page. Another issue is that this page can move around in the URL, IE:

mydomain.com/wp-login.php

mydomain.com/somecracp/wp-login.php

mydomain.com/wp-login.php?xys=5653

I need a regex which will detect the domain name of mydomain.com and the wp-login.php anywhere in the URL. I then need to force https for them. Can anyone build me the code please?

UPDATE:
I may have found part of the issue. It would seem that the login page itself is also trying to do some redirection. When I access the admin section of the site http://mysite.com/wp-admin it detects that you aren't logged in; it then redirects you to the login page but appends a redirect_to query string at the end like so:

```
http://mydomain.com/subdomain/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fsubdomain%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

It seems to do this so that once you log in successfully it can redirect you to the admin section you previously tried to access. This "redirect_to" and what comes after it is the URL it will redirect to once you log in.

I won't to go into details as to why but is there a way I can force it overwrite the above URL to go to mydomain.com/wp-login.php with none of the rediret_to crap?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule wp-login.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]
```

The regex part of the `RewriteRule` checks to see if there is any instance of `wp-login.php` in the request, and if there is, redirect to https.

Comment: Thats working a lot better than anything I have so far. It now logs in and out correctly. Another issue has come about though. Please have a read of my update above and see if you have any idea how to fix it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-login.php [NC]
RewriteRule https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The rewriteCondition will check if https is off and request uri contains wp-login.php, then redirect.